# How to enable Cors in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

I'm learning **Angular 2**. This is my service that's supposed to pull data from an ASP.NET Web api application.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ExpenseService {
  private _expUrl = "http://localhost:65400/api/expenses";

  constructor(private _http: Http){}    

  getExpenses(): Observable<IExpense[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._expUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IExpense[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('ALL: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError)
  }    
  //more here...
}
```

The above code is working fine in Microsoft Edge. However, in Chrome and FireFox, I'm getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:65400/api/expenses. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
```

I've enabled CORS in my web api as suggested by many posts.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddCors();
   //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
       ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  //...
  app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/"));
}
```

That didn't change the outcome. I'm still getting the same error in Chrome and FireFox while Edge is working just fine.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Client side code is completely irrelevant , CORS must be implemented server side and it is the browser that determines it's availability, not javascript. Your question should be how to implement it in .NET not angular. This should not be hard to research....there are thousands of CORS questions on this site, whole web sites dedicated to it and lots of other web resources

Comment: Guys, stop voting every question down. I don't know anything about CORS. I'm getting an error that's why I'm seeking help here. Should I change the title?

Comment: Yes and you should do some research. Hundreds of CORS questions get asked every week

Comment: @charlietfl, try to be nice. You are free to help. Don't you think I've done research on the subject. I posted the code that I found online.

Comment: Obviously not ... as per answer below what you are looking for is right in the manual. Asking questions here should be a last resort and my point is that this is not hard to research

Comment: Not everybody has your level of understanding. I respect people who answers my questions. That's why I'll end it here and thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I think he made his research because he found out about configuration on the server side. Even if the answer is out there doesnt mean that he is not allowed to ask a question. Because sometimes you find the answer but its not working for your code, this is why you can post the code and tell others what you have done so far, all these steps has done by him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is something that are enforced by the client, supported by the server.

CORS is there to help you as a user. It restrict the possibility for a client, like javascript on host google.com, to call a service on mydomain.com. This is a cross-domain call, which Chrome and FireFox does not allow. (Would assume that Edge also supported this). If you are hosting a service and client on some host and port, CORS is not used.

A service must define which host from a cross-domain is allowed. This can either be from all or from a specific host.

To allow access from all host do the following:

**Configuration**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

**Controller**

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class TestController : ApiController
```

If your service is a public service, be aware of the consequences.

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: I'm using asp.net core.

Comment: Add that as a tag, I have no way of knowing. But it is the same principle. Follow the link....

Comment: I've looked to this link as well. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3349/pagination-in-angularjs-by-resolving-cors-in-web-api-with-aspnet-core